# How to change icon of a MAC OS folder using Python Script and Terminal commands?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, icons, xattr

I am trying to write the Code in Python to Change the Icon of a Mac OS X folder using just the Python Script (Without XCODE or any other API).
The procedure is that I have a **icon.icns** file , I need to change the folder icon to the **icon.icns** file using the python script.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet? I'm also curious about it

Comment: Let we have a icon.icns file:

Read the com.apple.ResourceFork extended attribute from the icon file
Set the com.apple.FinderInfo extended attribute with folder icon flag
Create a Icon file (name: Icon\r) inside the target folder
Set extended attributes com.apple.FinderInfo & com.apple.ResourceFork for icon file (name: Icon\r)
Hide the icon file (name: Icon\r)
We can use stat and xattr modules to do this.

Comment: Will add the code in my git for further reference

Comment: I'd love to see your code to do this.  Can you link to your git where you put it?  Thanks @TougherApollo1

Answer (score 2):

> Let we have a icon.icns file:
>
> 1. Read the com.apple.ResourceFork extended attribute from the icon file
> 2. Set the com.apple.FinderInfo extended attribute with folder icon flag
> 3. Create a Icon file (name: Icon\r) inside the target folder
> 4. Set extended attributes com.apple.FinderInfo & com.apple.ResourceFork for icon file (name: Icon\r)
> 5. Hide the icon file (name: Icon\r)
>
> We can use stat and xattr modules to do this.